# Android set outline corner radius for custom radio buttons group

Tags: android

this screen shot is custom radio button group as an simple switch buttons

[image]

when i click on Search or Offers as end of buttons, buttons don't have corner radius size, for example:

[image]

[image]

my `toggle_widget_background` xml laout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/md_pink_A700" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/md_pink_500" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

now how can i set corner radius for left and right buttons?

this xml layout not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:drawable="@color/md_pink_A700" android:state_checked="true">
        <shape  >
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:topRightRadius="7dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item  android:drawable="@color/md_pink_500" android:state_checked="true">
        <shape  >
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:topRightRadius="7dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item  android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_checked="true">
        <shape  >
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
                android:topRightRadius="7dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use separate toggle layouts for left and right radio buttons. And then use shape layouts for each state.
For example,
For **left**, Use the following type of layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unselected_left" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_selected_left" />

</selector>
```

For **right**, use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_unselected_right" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_selected_right" />

</selector>
```

The drawables are layouts having shape and colour